# Extract Text From PDF File using Smalot/pdfparser return empty result

Tags: php, pdf, pdfparser

I want to extract text from a pdf file using smalot/pdfparser,but i've got empty result on some file.
the pdf file without password and open normally using chrome.
I've tried another pdf file working fine.

this is my code

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser(); // Parse pdf file using Parser library 
$pdf = $parser->parseFile($file);
$metaData = $pdf->getDetails();
print_r($metaData); 
$pages  = $pdf->getPages();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $text = $page->getText();
            echo "<div>".$text."</div>";
}
echo $file;
```

the result just

```
Array
Array
(
    [Producer] => cairo 1.17.4 (https://cairographics.org
    [Pages] => 1
)
<div></div>D:\web\D\public\pdf_po/123.pdf
```

can anyone explain my problem?
this is my pdf file : [www.mediafire.com/file/azb7yddqo2ry55j/123.pdf/file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/azb7yddqo2ry55j/123.pdf/file)

Comment: Implement error handling to catch exceptions so you can get a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: @KarlHill I have done it, but no error appears

Comment: @KJ please share your code, thanks

Comment: @KJ I also applied your code, it's still empty

Comment: You could try with [this library](https://github.com/christian-vigh-phpclasses/PdfToText).

Comment: @Olivier .Thank You. The file has been successfully extracted. Unfortunately the data in the table cannot be read correctly. Is there a way so that the data per column does not merge with each other?

Answer (score 0):

PDFtoText

Should give you the best results since there are no table divisions in a PDF text:

[image]

So when that text layout is reversed into Word.txt or as suitable for any other Text Processor you can simply draw the tables or divisions around the text. The alternative is import into Excel or any other "Spreadsheet" program.

Then it's easier to cut and paste real tabular data, or use it any other way. The primary trick is ensuring you extract **exactly the gridlike way** it is stored in a PDF and the closest to that is reprinting the text file via PDFtoText (there are many versions so find one that suits your needs).